# How do i extract a specific string in a list

Tags: python, list

I need to extract a the first string in my list alone
then I need to extract the second string in my list in another variable.

```
username_password = ["wil15","password"]
```

i have tried:
username = username_password[0]

Comment: *"I have tried: `username = username_password[0]`"*. Are you sure you have? Otherwise I don't think you would be asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your list always contains two items, you can do this:

```
var1, var2 = ["wil15", "password"]
```

That will assign `"wil15"` to `var1` and "password" to `var2`.